# How to set env in controller for dacastro4 laravel-gmail package?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, gmail-api, laravel-package

I am trying to implement Gmail API for CRM based on laravel, where users can store multiple Google credentials, and using those credentials users can log in with their Google account.

I used [dacastro4 laravel-gmail package](https://github.com/dacastro4/laravel-gmail), but for `dacastro4/laravel-gmail` package by default design, those Google credentials are stored in .env file of the laravel project.

.env

```
GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID=
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET=
GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URI=
```

`

I tried setting the .env variable in the controller constructor function, but not working.
for example,

```
env('GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID',$project_id);
//OR
putenv("GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID=".$project_id);
//OR
config(['GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID' => $project_id])
```

Also tried setting in the vendor dacastro4 laravel-gmail package, but the database model is not accessible.

How can I set multiple Google credentials from the controller?

Thank You.

Comment: you wouldn't set the env variables you would set a config value ... it pulls the env variables for the config at `gmail.php` ... https://github.com/dacastro4/laravel-gmail/blob/master/src/config/gmail.php   those are the config values ... the config file should have been published to your `config` folder for reference

Answer (score 2):

You can set this data using the `config()` method, seeing as that's how Laravel accesses `.env` variables.

Create a config file for your variables:

config/gmail.php

```
<?php

return [
    'project_id' => env('GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID'),
    'client_id' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    'redirect_url' => env('GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URI', '/'),
]
```

Then set values in your controller on the go using:

```
config(['gmail.project_id' => $project_id]);
```

and retrieve the values using:

```
config('gmail.project_id');
```